# Dialogic - how do I set my BTN (billing telephone number) for outgoing calls

Tags: telephony

I have an application that uses Dialogic voice boards with PRI phone lines. We make phone calls on behalf of schools and spoof the caller ID to get the school's telephone number to display. When making outbound calls, we set the school's phone number in gc_makecallblk.isdn.origination_phone_number. That works great.

The problem is that our phone vendor is using the caller ID number when determining billing rates, and so most of our calls are getting billed as in-state calls, which are more expensive. I've been told by the vendor that I need to set the BTN (billing telephone number, he also called it ANI, but I think that is a more generic term) to get the correct, out-of-state, billing rates.

I have searched Dialogic's API documentation and I have not been able to find any information about setting the BTN. Are there any Dialogic/Telephony experts out there who know how to set it?

Answer (score 0):

What protocol are you talking about and is this on TDM or VoIP? I am an Aculab expert and we have similar products to Dialogic so perhaps I could help.

It could be that you simply need to set the "National/International" call parameter or edit the ANI (also known as CLI). The more information you can share, the better.

- ChrisL@Aculab